# how do you use azure to setup logins and storage?

Tags: azure, cloud

we currently have two servers which manage both the emails in and out, they are where we store all the logins for the internal network and we also have a z drive where we store files.

We would like to move this to azure, but not sure how you do this exactly?

We currently host our web application here, so we're now ready to move the rest over.

There are 40+ staff and all of them use all of office's software (outlook, word, excel etc). Is it worth moving to office 365 and how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like rather than Azure, you'd want to look into Office 365 for this purpose.

They have guides on how to set up accounts and migrate your Active Directory users at http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/support/getting-started-with-office-365-for-business-FX103993883.aspx

As far as your file share goes (the Z: drive) you would probably want to handle much of that via the SharePoint sites they provide, since neither Azure nor Office 365 provide a native method to share files using a Windows File Share-like interface. It depends on how large the file sizes are as well - the SharePoint sites cannot host files greater than 250MB.